# How should I solve the overlapping numbers for y-axis of a plot?

Tags: r

[image]

some overlapping problems like this.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=`data$x1`,y=`data$x2`))+geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and how do I include the pic directly when I post?

Comment: Please use `dput(data)` an paste the output editing the question!

Comment: I'm going out on a limb by saying that ... those are not `numeric`, they're likely `character` or `factor` ... in which case, my first suggestion is to use `as.numeric` on at least that field. BTW: when `ggplot(data, ...)`, there is rarely a need to reference `data` directly again, so you should also trim your code to be `ggplot(data, aes(x=x1, y=x2)) + geom_point()`, once we get past the number-thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
data$x2 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$x2)
# same for $x1?
ggplot(data, aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_point()
```